# Learning Java - Tell me more about constructors that has input variable with data type of another class

Tags: java, android, variables, constructor

Im new to Java, so i hope you guys will teach me a thing or two. Here we go:

1)Why would i use constructors? I got so many issues with contructors, because i dont know why and how to apply them and i really need practice, before i fully can understand it.

2)How would your constructor look like, when you got:
2 classes - Vehicles and Car. Car needs access to variables, in the Vehicles class, so i can start working on methods with certain variables(that belongs to Vehicles class), from the Car class. I just need to see some examples.

3)I got this from another question(thanks again, for helping me out):

```
public Vehicles(Car frame) {
        this.testingobj = frame;
    }
```

It works, but why does work and what does it do? I use it on every class i create. It seem like it can contact my Car class, when i press a JButton, to activate a method in Vehciles class. Is there anything i should consider in contrast of question )2?

Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: This is more a question-and-answer site than a tutorial site.  Have you checked out the Oracle Java tutorials?

Comment: Oh, im sorry then. I did but, but i would like to see some specific examples, it would be much easier for me to understand.

Comment: `Car` should probably be a subclass of `Vehicle`, and `Vehicle` almost certainly shouldn't take a `Car` argument in a constructor.  By making `Car` a subclass of `Vehicle`, an object of class `Car` will have all the (public & protected) methods and properties that an object of class `Vehicle` would, plus whatever is added to `Car`.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Answer (score 2):

A class definition is like a blueprint. It defines the API for the class and what it can do. But a blueprint is just a blueprint. It isn't useful until you actually *have something* to work with. It's nice to read all the specs on a Bentley; it is even nicer to see one and drive it.

This is where a constructor comes in. It creates a new instance of the class by reserving space in memory for it and initializing it so that it is in a proper state ready to do all the things its class definition promises its clients it can do.

As for your example, I think you need to understand object-oriented design before you worry about the mechanics of constructors. Why would `Car` need to access a `Vehicle`? A car *is a* vehicle.

You need to think about what you are trying to accomplish and understand how objects work together to get things done. Then you can worry about constructors and ultimately Android development.

Comment: You know, just like the example you see everywhere. Fx. MountainBike needs to access Bike, because they share common variables?

Comment: In that example, `MountainBike` is a subclass of `Bike`, not an argument sent to a `Bike` constructor.

Comment: @nhgrif is right. Those classes have an inheritance relationship--something you need to read up on. But keep in mind that you don't use inheritance just to share variables. You use it to describe a relationship between classes that share *behavior*.

Comment: This is the example @user3074245 references: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html